# Generating certificate for iOS using codename one certificate wizard

Tags: ios, codenameone

I tried to generate the certificate using codename one certificate wizard but was stopped at "select team". I don't have any option and the next button is not taking me anywhere. When I hit the back button, it takes me back to sign in page.  Please, how do I solve this?

Must I become a paid developer member of apple before I can develop iOS app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to create an Apple Developer Account.
Certificates are created in the Apple Member Center which is a managing center for the developer account.

Comment: I mean must I pay the $99 subscription fee before I can test my app on my device

Comment: Yes you or someone you know needs to pay Apple

Comment: Hi,  Tim and Shai  am happy for making it clearer. Please I am just starting up with iOS using codename one and I can't pay this since I don't have big project am running now.  Also, I don't know anyone who has account with apple since we don't use apple as such in Nigeria. Please is there anyone who can help me do that?

Comment: Unfortunately , i only have a entreprise account used by my company i can't let you use it (you understand why ;) )
Maybe try the student developer program if it's avalaible for you : https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/enroll/